# C# how to remove a signature from an xml file?

Tags: c#

I have an XML file that is digitally signed. Is there an easy way to remove this signature in C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming it has a `<Signature>` Element

You can just remove it using Linq and Resave.

```
// Find the <Signature> Element
XElement signElement = doc.Descendants("Signature").FirstOrDefault<XElement>();

signElement.Remove();

doc.Save("NonSignedFile.xml");
```

Comment: ok figured out the problem, it appears the xml file is run through some kind of zip compression first.